# How to? PHP & MySQL sortdata in a function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am stuck in writing a PHP function. What I need to do is pass on about 10 - 12 ID into an array and then sort them by name in mysql database and then print some statements. I got this far where I manually add an ID number and it prints the information I need but at this point I have to sort the data before using those ID numbers.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
<?php
function print_software_info($id) {
  $appinfo = "SELECT * FROM `appinfo` WHERE `id` = ".intval($id);
  $rt = mysql_query($appinfo) or die(mysql_error("Could not retrieve database information"));
  echo $rt['name'];
  echo $rt['image'];
}
?>
<?php 
print_software_info(217);
print_software_info(179);
print_software_info(8);
?>
```

Comment: actually i didnt get you what you exactly want.? please explain more.

Comment: I have a table with following fields. 1) ID 2) Name 3) Image_location 4) About. 

What I need to do is pass on ID values in an array and sort them by name and print information about them

Comment: Glad to say that thin function's design is terrible. Against all rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with

```
$ids = array(13, 14, 250, ... );
```

First (optional for now, but keep in mine) make sure they're all integer (sanitize)

```
$ids = array_map('intval',$ids);
```

You need to build a query like this

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `appinfo` WHERE `id` IN (". implode(',',$ids) ." ) ORDER BY name";

$result = mysql_query($q);
```

Then go through each rows..

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->image;
}
```

Comment: This is more like it. Thanks.